# I am trying to get this run.bat to work on Linux CentOS

Tags: java, linux, batch-file, centos

Well I am trying to get this run.bat to work on CentOS and am having a tough time trying to get it to load the main class. On my server it is located at server/build/net/com/Server(mainclass)

Here is my run.bat

```
@echo off
title SunScape World 1 - Port 43594
cd ../build
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe" net/com/Server 43594
pause
```

Here is what I am using on CentOS as a .sh

```
cd ../build
"java" .net.com.Server 43594
pause
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:          //pvpscape/build/net/com/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..pvpscape.build.net.com.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: ./pvpscape/build/net/com/Server. Program will exit.
```

Comment: No clue, but have you tried "net.com.Server" or "net/com/Server"? There seems to be one dot too many in your attempt. ".net.com.Server" doesn't really look 100% right in my eyes, but this might be a syntax I'm not fully aware of yet...

Comment: unfortunately I have tried that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The error refers to ./pvpscape/build/net/com/Server , so somewhere you're referring to ./pvpscape/build/net/com/Server instead of net/com/Server, try to figure out where.

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy,

Unfortunately bat files are for DOS, and do not run on Linux.  The scripting language for Linux are bash scripts (historically sh scripts).  Below is an intro guide to bash scripting:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Reviewing you bat script, I see that you are trying to enter the "../build" directory, and then use java to run 'net/com/Server' with the argument 43594 and then sleep.  In linux bash scripting we would accomplish this with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ../build
java net/com/Server 43594
sleep 10
```

You will then need to make the script executable:

```
chmod 755 run.sh
```

And finally to run this script:

```
# ./run.sh
```